# Orange 3 - How can a String feature behave as a coefficient?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, linear-regression, orange

I'm studying machine learning with data. I have a table including features and a target variable which is the price as in the following.

[image]

When I want to figure out the coefficients to obtain linear regression formula, I get the following table in which I don't understand how the coefficient is found for strings e.g. `KARTAL`, `3+1`?

[image]

[image]

Secondly, There are coefficients as you can see, how can I write its formula since there are negative values and strings? I don't know how to apply them as a formula?

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). For "Why doesn't my code work questions" that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.